# scrollIntoView ain't working on my react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a chatbot.
Below is my React component.I am tring to scroll the `MessageListWrapper` to the bottom every time `messageList` gets updated. But it doesn't seem to work, in the sense the div doesn't scroll to the bottom. I looked around and did a bit of research but unable to figure out why this doesn't work. :/

```
const MessageListContainer =  styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1;
    height: 85%;
`;

 const MessageListWrapper =  styled.div`
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100%; 
 `;

const MessageList = ({messageList}) => {
    
    const messagesEndRef = useRef();

    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        const {current} = messagesEndRef;
        current.scrollIntoView();
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
        scrollToBottom()
    }, [messageList]);

    return (
        <>
            <MessageListContainer>
                <MessageListWrapper ref={messagesEndRef} >
                    {
                        (messageList && messageList.length) ? (messageList.map(..<snipped for brevity>..)) :
                        <></>
                    }
                </MessageListWrapper>
            </MessageListContainer>
        </>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To anyone landing on this post with the same issue, I resolved the issue by using

```
    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        const {current} = messagesEndRef;
        current.scrollTo(0,current.scrollHeight);
    }
```